# Como resgatar valor do checkbox no formulário usando serialize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um formulário no qual é criado dinamicamente usando o método `append`. O resultado é algo nesse formato:

```
$('#form').append("<tr><td class='td-min'><input value='"+item.role+"'"+
    +" name='"+item.prefix+"' type='checkbox'/> "+item.role+"</td></tr>'");
```

Acima seria basicamente um item do formulário, no qual é gerado uma lista de itens dinamicamente.

Abaixo, usando AJAX, é como pretendo gravar no banco de banco de dados, porém não sei com resgatar os valores do `checkbox`. Veja:

```
jQuery('#form').submit(function(){
    var dados = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://api.server.com/resgata",
        success: function( data )
        {

        }
    });
  return false;
});
```

Como resgatar valores dos `checkbox's` dinâmicos (tanto *checked* quanto *unchecked*) no formulário usando o método `serialize()`? É possível?

Comment: Ao se referir à valores você se refere à `checked` ou `value`?

Comment: @Matheus `checked` como diz na própria pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é obter os valores dos `checkboxs` e concatenar com o método *serialize*, visto que `serialize()` transforma os valores do formulário em uma *querystring* válida:

```
jQuery('#form').submit(function(){
    var dados = jQuery(this).serialize() + getUnchecks();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://api.server.com/resgata",
        success: function( data )
        {

        }
    });
  return false;
});

function getUnchecks() {
  var uncheckdItemsStr = '';
  var domElement = document.getElementById("form");
  jQuery(domElement).find("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    uncheckdItemsStr += '&' + jQuery(this).prop('name') + '=' + jQuery(this).prop('value');
  });

  return uncheckdItemsStr;
}
```

O retorno de `getUnchecks` será algo como:

```
&abc=cba&qwe=ewq&qwe=ewq
```

Comment: Então se é uma alternativa, quer dizer que não é possível resgatar os `checkbox's` com `serialize()` diretamente?

Comment: Na verdade @acklay, com checks fiz um teste e foram serializados todos eles foram serializados, [veja](https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/aLhsbtvj/1/). É dessa forma que está implementando?

Comment: Sim, muito próximo do que você fez. Porém quando o valor do checkbox for 0, também tenho que enviar para a base também. ´Me parece que só é resgatado com `serialize` quando o `input` está `checked`.

Comment: Da pra fazer o caminho inverso @acklay, Concatenar somente os *checks* não checados. Atualizei a resposta. A documentação não deixa explicíto essa condição, mas faz sentido não serializar um check unchecked porque em um formulário foi uma opção não selecionada, mas se para você essa informação é importante pode obter dessa forma.

Comment: Pra mim é importante porque se o usuário desmarcar algo que já estava marcado, tenho que excluir/alterar na base de dados a chave que foi desmarcada.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e frisei melhor: (tanto `checked` quanto `unchecked`)

Comment: Os checked eles já vai obter, os unchecked pode ser pela minha função.

Comment: Não é desnecessário @Matheus, o `serialize()` já vai obter os inputs selecionados, se a função abranger ambos vai haver duplicados, entende?! Quanto a sua sugestão, ela é bem vinda, talvez você possa incluir na sua resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Com o jQuery você pode fazer isso basicamente:

```
// Conversão de formulário para objeto Array
var dados = $(this).serializeArray();

// Conversão de objeto para URL
var query = $.param(dados);
```

`dados` deveria ser algo como:

```
[
    { name: 'nameDeUmaCheckBox', value: 'valorDaCheckBox' },
    ...
]
```

Se você quer que o valor de cada checkbox serialize como seu respectivo estado `checked`, experimente:

```
var transform = $(this).clone();

// Muda o valor das checkboxes para o estado checked
// (0 ou 1 no exemplo)
transform.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Então:

```
var dados = $(transform).serializeArray();
var query = $.param(dados);
```